# Is it safe to remove log files?

Tags: 14.04, log

Sorry if it's a stupid question. I would like to free up some space and /var/log is full of logs. I do not intend to use any of the log files, so I don't care if they get deleted or not. But I afraid that it may affect the functionality of the services that produce logs. I understand that it may depend on the program that produces the logs. but Do you think it would be safe to remove regular services and system log such as:

```
alternatives.log
auth.log
boot.log                 
mail.log     
syslog
dmesg
dpkg
faillog
fontconfig.log
kern.log
wtmp
nginx/*
apt/*
btmp
```

Comment: I wouldn't actually delete them but configure `logrotate` to compress and dispose of them sooner (i.e. not keep 7 generations but just 2 for example).

Comment: Few single-users *intend* to review their logfiles. But when something breaks those files can be invaluable. Record how to undo whatever solution you choose in case you need logging in the future.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually safe.
 you can also zero them out 
 `> /var/log/nginx/error.log` for example.
You can also but these in a script and call it with cron

Crontab:
`1 5 */2 * 0 /home/user/scripts/delnginxlogs.sh`

Actual script:

```
cd /var/log/nginx
rm *.gz
> domain-ssl-access.log
> domain.org-ssl-error.log
> domain.com-ssl-access.log
> domain.com.-ssl-error.log
```

etc,etc

Comment: Funny schedule for the cronjob: it means [_At 05:01 on every 2nd day-of-month if it's on Sunday._](https://crontab.guru/#1_5_*/2_*_0) ;-) _My_ computer isn't usually turned on at that time.

Comment: I saw you got an nginx in there.
I assumed its a web server
Btw if the answer suits you lpease vote and accept it. ty

Comment: You shouldn't push the OP after just ~40 minutes to upvote and/or accept an answer. Instead, let the OP take his/her time and after some time you _may_ point them to [_What should I do when someone answers my question?_](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) instead.